# Problems with the DocumentSettingPanel SlotFill in Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, jsx, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to figure out Gutenberg's SlotFills in WordPress. Specifically, trying to explore what is and isn't possible out of the box for customization of the post editing interface sidebar. ('Carousel Item' in the picture below is a custom post type I'm working with.)

[image]

SlotFills appear to be a tool I can use to add my own custom controls to the sidebar. From the [Gutenberg documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-document-setting-panel/#example) I have the following code working as you can see in the subsequent screenshot.

```jsx
    const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
    const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;

    const myDocumentSettingPanel = () => (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
            name="custom-panel"
            title="Custom Panel"
            className="custom-panel"
        >
            Custom Panel Contents
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );
    
    registerPlugin( 'my-document-setting-panel', {
        render: myDocumentSettingPanel,
        icon: 'palmtree',
    } );
```

[image]

So far so good. However, the icon is not showing next to the title of the custom panel as the various examples indicate it should (including [this video presentation](https://wordpress.tv/2022/11/18/extending-wordpress-using-slotfill/) by Ryan Welcher--PluginDocumentSettingPanel discussion starts at 14:28). I suspect it's because something is not included/imported appropriately in my code. I have no errors in my js console for this page. 'palmtree' is one of the [Dashicons](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#palmtree), and I'm guessing the library is simply not available in the context I'm in. I'm new enough to all of this though and the documentation is obtuse enough (for me at least) that I'm having difficulty figuring out what's wrong.

What [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-plugins/#registerplugin) I've been able to find on WordPress' registerPlugin() javascript function doesn't define what it expects for the icon, which doesn't help. Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. [Here's the detail](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/418424/problems-with-the-documentsettingpanel-slotfill-in-gutenberg).

Correct code should read as follows:

```jsx
    const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
    const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;

    const myDocumentSettingPanel = () => (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
            name="custom-panel"
            title="Custom Panel"
            className="custom-panel"
            icon='palmtree'
        >
            Custom Panel Contents
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );
    
    registerPlugin( 'my-document-setting-panel', {
        render: myDocumentSettingPanel,
        // icon: 'palmtree',
    } );
```